# VBA dictionary with composite keys

Tags: vba, dictionary, tuples

Is there a structure in VBA that will allow using tuples as keys, similar to Python? I'm looking to store a large matrix of values in an associative array, indexed by key names in both dimensions.

EDIT:

Here's an example of a simple data table:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        | City 1 | City 2 | City 3 | City 4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| City 1 |    0   |   7    |    8   |    6   |
| City 2 |        |   0    |    1   |    6   |
| City 3 |        |        |    0   |    5   |
| City 4 |        |        |        |    0   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to be able to store these values in an associative array (dictionary), as they will be read millions of times throughout the execution of my script. I'd like to be able to have the dictionary keys be tuples. Thus, the I'd like to create a dictionary (we'll call it Distance), where the keys and values are:

```
(City 1, City 2) = 7
(City 1, City 3) = 8
(City 1, City 4) = 6
(City 2, City 3) = 1
(City 2, City 4) = 6
(City 3, City 4) = 5
```

I would access the distance between city 1 and city 2 with something like this:

```
Distance("City 1", "City 2")
```

Comment: AFAIK, no. Each `item` for a particular `key` can be an array but not the key itself. Or maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: No, you didn't. I actually only need a long or double for the item, but I'd like to have a composite key. I know I can use a 2-dimensional array and use integer indices, but I was hoping to use strings. Essentially, I have a giant matrix of distances between cities that I'd like to store in an array-like structure. Thus I'd like to be able to access, say, Distance("Seattle", "Chicago").

Comment: I'm confused now. :) Can you illustrate it? That data you need to pass into the dictionary? Which goes to the `Item` and which goes as `Keys`.

Comment: See edit. The keys would be the city pairs, and the item would be a distance.

Comment: Ah so the intersection contains it's distance correct?

Comment: You could make a dictionary of dictionaries, which I think would do what you want. It's not very pretty, but very doable.

Comment: @L42 Correct. When I've worked in Python before with various optimization problems, I've used a composite key dictionary structure to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel I suggest you to use a function that in any cell you can find your valueby a simple fornula like `=Distance("ct1","ct2")`:

And function is:

```
Public Function Distance(RowCity As String, ColCity As String) As String
    Dim RowNo As Long, ColNo As Long
    RowNo = 0: ColNo = 0

    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet
        RowNo = .Columns("A").Find(What:=RowCity).Row
        ColNo = .Rows(1).Find(What:=ColCity).Column

        If RowNo <> 0 And ColNo <> 0 Then
            Distance = Trim(.Cells(RowNo, ColNo).Value & " ")
        Else
            Distance = "#N/A"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

> **Note:** When you are using Excel, Excel sheets are two-dimensional arrays with many options that you need.

---

There is a kind of dictionary that you can use (from COM objects):

```
Dim dict As Object
Dim key As Variant

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.Add "City 1", "City 2"

For Each key In dict.Keys
    If key = condiction Then
        'use dict.Item(key)
    End If
Next key
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm actually not looking to use this in a worksheet. My primary concern is actually read speed here, as this matrix of values will be accessed a few million times throughout the course of my script.

Comment: @AustinWismer I don't know where is your matrix or how you fill it, But as I noted : If you store your matrix in an Excel sheet it can give you a very good speed ;).

Comment: Basically, I have a matrix of values stored in a worksheet. For speed of access, I would like to read this matrix from the spreadsheet, and store it as an array. Since the values of this matrix will be accessed millions of times throughout the execution of the script, it is much faster to read these values from an array than from the spreadsheet every single time. My question is whether or not there is a way to store them in an associative array where each value (item) can have keys composed of multiple values (a tuple, for instance).

Comment: @AustinWismer I found a dictionary type that you can use in VBA ;).

Comment: I'm familiar with a scripting dictionary, but I don't believe it allows for composite keys does it? I've ended up using a dictionary, but I've concatenated the two strings for each city into a single key.